# Angular Js giving error while separating view,library and controller file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made three directory for view,controller and library.
In library I kept angular.min.js.

In controller I have kept controller.js.
In view directory,I have kept cartingApp.html file.

```js
//cartcontroller.js

var ShoppingCartModule = angular.module('ShoppingCart',[]) ;
ShoppingCartModule.controller('CartingController',function CartingController($scope) {
    $scope.channels = [
                        { channelName : 'c1',seconds:'200', rate: '10' },
                        { channelName : 'c2',seconds:'200', rate: '20' },
                        { channelName : 'c3',seconds:'200', rate: '30' },
                        { channelName : 'c4',seconds:'200', rate: '40' },
                   ] ;
                   
    $scope.remove = function($index) { //alert($index);return ;
        $scope.channels.splice($index,1) ;
    }
}
        ) ;
```

```html
//html file
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="ShoppingCart">
    <head>
        <title>Shopping Cart</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controller/CartingController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="CartingController">
            <h1>Network Ro Summary</h1>
            <div ng-repeat='item in channels'>
                <span> {{item.channelName}}</span>
                <input ng-model="item.rate" />
                <span>{{item.seconds | currency }}</span>
                <span>{{item.seconds*item.rate | currency }}</span>
                <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
            </div> 
            
        </div> 
            
    </body>
</html>
```

When I am accessing the page cartingApp.html from Browser,I am not able to access ,it is giving error.
But I am keeping all three files in same directory,I am easily accessing it.
Please let me know what is error ?

Comment: I don't see any part of your code that uses cartingApp.html

Comment: Have ur controller/CartingController.js gets called?

Comment: cartingApp.html is html page .... code is not running....while keeping all files in different directory

Comment: instead of <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script> use ....<script src="library/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: @VikasKumar as you said *When I am accessing the page cartingApp.html from Browser,I am not able to access ,it is giving error.* What is the error you got?

Comment: There is a chance to get this kind of issue. 
Path is not set correctly.
Check the permission of downloaded JS file.
MainApp should call each page, So be aware of giving mainApp(Else create a js for mainApp and call this script initially)

Comment: Hi Jagadeesh,it is not called.....

Comment: Hi jagadeesh....it is not giving error.... it is just displaying :--- Network Ro Summary
{{item.channelName}} {{item.seconds | currency }} {{item.seconds*item.rate | currency }}

Comment: So please check with this `<script src="../controller/CartingController.js"></script>`. Right now use google api untill you get clear to call the controller.js and you can replace the library file

Comment: when I am keeping cartingcontroller file in controller directory and angular.min.js in same directory of view file,and changing the path of angular.min.js .....it is giving error...  Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$injector/modulerr?p0=ShoppingCart&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%

Comment: This is my sample. `<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"                 type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/mainApp.js"                     type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/loginController.js"             type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"              type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/styles.css"                     type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="loginController"> </body></html>`

Comment: Hey Jagadeesh....it is working....thanks a lot ..... can you please tell me specific issue...why it happened ?

Comment: Which one you tried?

Comment: <script src="../controller/CartingController.js"></script>

Comment: I will post as a answer.

Comment: why did not earlier one work ?

Comment: Did you got your issue now @VikasKumar ? If so then please accept the answer and vote for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not getting loaded as your HTML is in  view directory. From there it looks for controller director in the view directory itself because You have specified:
src ="controller/CartingController.js"

Which basically looks for controller directory in the view directory itself, which is not present.
So 
src="../controller/CartingController.js" should correct your error!

In future try to see console to see why your code is not working. And yes to dynamically load controllers and HTML's you can us ng-route or ui-router etc

Answer (score 0):

When you link a script in your html, then it should be accessible.
Means it must be load. If you can't load / set properly..
Then set a link with "../". This will load the script the file from the its root directory.

```
<script src="../controller/CartingController.js"></script>
```

So it will called.

Comment: Hi Jagadeesh,instead of writing hard code ,is there any way to load it dynamically....